# Angular2 change detection on property binding to model method

Tags: angular, data-binding

I have an object, let's say User. User has it's own class:

```
class User {
  comments: Comments[];

  get commentsSomething() {
    const comments = this.comments.doSomething();
    return comments;
  }
}
```

And I have a component, which is rendered in *ngFor and has something like:

```
<some-component *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user.commentsSomething">
```

`commentsSomething` is constant value, which is calculated once. But it somehow triggers change detection on some-component on multiple actions across application.

```
@Component(...some-component)
ngOnChanges() {
  console.log('it goes crazy');
}
```

There are too many, way too many 'it goes crazy' in console.

Problem goes away if I construct User class like this:

```
class User {
  comments: Comments[];
  commentsSomethingHolder: any = null;

  get commentsSomething() {
    if (isNull(this.commentsSomethingHolder)) {
      this.commentsSomethingHolder = this.comments.doSomething();
    }

    return this.commentsSomethingHolder;
  }
}
```

I understand this is somehow connected to a reference. But I cannot understand why is this happening, if "commentsSomething" method is run only once per item in this *ngFor. Moreover, component above `some-component` doesn't fire ngOnChanges.

So, how should I pass this data, so angular doesn't repeat my calculations?

Comment: when does it trigger `ngOnChanges`? what do you do in the parent component?

Comment: I do only things in other components, ``some-component`` parent component's ngOnChanges does not fire.

Comment: maybe be create a plunker